# PHP, MySQL - Repeating query inside of loop until successful, is it just a resource drain?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to improve user experience, by increasing the chances that successful queries will be carried out.

The queries in question are simple, quick operations - something like:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT val1, val2, val3 FROM table WHERE id=?');
$stmt->execute(array($someID));
...
```

or

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO table (val1, val2, val3) VALUES (?, ?, ?)');
$stmt->execute(array($val1, $val2, $val3));
```

and so forth. No joins, no copious amounts of data. The queries take fractions of a second.

Because they are so quick, I thought that it would be appropriate and safe to loop through the same query multiple times, if it fails.

Something like:

```
function test($someVal, $db){
    $db->beginTransaction();
    try{
        $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT val1, val2, val3 FROM table WHERE id=?');
        $stmt->execute(array($someVal));

        $result = $stmt->fetchAll();

        $db->commit();

        if(count($result)){
            $arr = array();
            $arr['val1'] = $result[0]['val1'];
            $arr['val2'] = $result[0]['val2'];
            $arr['val3'] = $result[0]['val3'];
        }else{
            return 'empty';
        }

        return $arr; // All went well!
    }catch(Exception $e){
        $db->rollBack();
        // note the exception
        return false;
    }

    return false;
}
```

and then looping a few times (not indefinitely, obviously)

```
$i = 0;
$tmp = test($someVal, $db);
while(!$tmp){
    $i++;
    if($i === 3){
        // report it
        exit();
    }

    $tmp = test($someVal, $db);
}

if($tmp === 'empty'){
    ...
}else{
    ...
}
```

So, the loop would attempt the query up to 3 times, pending two initial failures.

But, **is it worth looping if it fails?**

So far, in my experience, I've never had a query fail that had proper syntax, that called the proper table, that had the proper values (except one time when server was down for maintenance). This would mean that if the query failed, it would continue to fail because something had gone wrong.

But surely someone, somewhere, has had a query fail... *just 'cause*? Hiccough in the connection, server reset, or what ever else might cause a query to fail this second, but succeed the next? And maybe a second (or third) attempt at pulling the data is all it takes...

Right? ... right?

Like I said, these aren't overly strenuous queries. But without their returned data, the user cannot proceed further.

Is it so uncommon for perfectly constructed queries to fail, that I'm just wasting time and resources with these repeat attempts? Once a failure, always a failure?

I understand that *it depends on the source of the failure*, and that certain errors (i.e. table doesn't exist), will continue to fail. I'm wondering if it's worth the extra calls to try and salvage the other failures?

Comment: I would say yes, unless you can specify actual cases/scenarios where it happens it is a waste of time. Because without being able to specify there is no way of knowing if your solution helps. You shouldn't hammer yourself through the problem, report it immediately instead of repeating (especially when there is no delay between tries).

And then in the future, if you actually have connectivity errors or what not you can build proper solutions for that specific problem instead of anticipating and building speculative solutions. =)

Comment: If you have connectivity issues then you are looking for the solution in the wrong direction (in fact, it is not a solution at all). If you have concurrency issues then, again, your attempt won't magically fix them. In fact, it will only make things worse; your server cannot handle all your requests and, instead of sending less requests, you want to fix it by sending more requests. If the concurrency makes your queries fail then you need more processing power (more RAM, CPUs or both).

Comment: A query is far more likely to fail because the database server is down or too busy than it is to fail "just because". In my experience, 99% of the times when a query fails, the same query done milliseconds later will also fail. I'd say building this mechanism is too much work for too little benefit.

Comment: your solution is not a solution. hammering the server when it refuses to exeucte the query won't help, 99.99% it will fail again so you'd be only contributing to its misery. if an error happens, then log it, trigger some email/text, whatever. just don't make this "optimisation" :)

Comment: Thanks, team! All very thorough answers, and very helpful. The closeness of the calls, and thus persistence of the failure, makes sense. I'd +1 you all again if I could, for not just leaving me to figure out "nope" or "that's dumb".

Comment: Never loop on a SELECT query, it is bad practice. Better to create a query which selects for all id you are looking for, while your loop enetered them into a variable, something like "SELECT ... WHERE id IN $id_values

Comment: Check maybe this will be helpful to understand why never to loop on SQL queries: [link](http://blog.tagpredict.com/index.php/2016/10/09/why-not-to-loop-on-sql-queries/)

Comment: I used to think like you years ago and I learned as @OliverMaksimovic said that %99.99 of the time it is going to fail again if it failed the first time. I always setup my queries on fail to send me an email with the exact query and the mysql error so I can work on it as they come in.

Comment: Your query is going to fail because the query is invalid or the database is inaccessible.  Doing another query right after that most likely won't give you a result.
Just return an error message or no results found at this moment.